# How to make better videos server?

Tags: android, ios, video, youtube, backend

I have an app, where i have to play to lots of videos,

when i tried to load videos from a dedicated server to my apps android and iOS, it takes too much time,

i upload videos on some cloud services, but the result is same,

i uploaded the video on video hosting service (Teachable, Thinkific), when the video is played on player provided by host, it plays better, but when i tried to load the video in app, it takes too much time.

i think i am missing something on server end.

Now, i need suggesstions,

1. What kind of service i have to use?
2. when a video is played on youtube, it does not include .flv or any other formate extension in address, so i think there is any logic to load videos more properly, please guide me, if you have any idea, like what protocol or logic is being used in better video playing

Answer (score 0):

for making video applications, there are some points to be considered first.

(usually, videos uploaded to youtube etc are played in chunks, m3u8 format for example)

1. Videos must be hosted in CDN network. (use AWS like service)
2. Videos must be in HLS, MSS  (AWS also provide this service)
3. App player must know about playing HLS protocol videos, (AVPLayer in iOS)

hope this answer gives you hint about your usecase

Comment: Thanks got the idea and working